# Query is performed every navigation

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following parse query inside the ViewDidAppear of my main menu and it queries whether an admin is signed in through Parse. The problem is that the query is performed every time the user navigates to the menu, and as it is the main screen; that is quite often. Here is the query, do I put it inside an if statement that basically says once signed in, stop querying or should be sticking it inside another method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

PFACL *roleACL = [PFACL ACL];
[roleACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
PFRole *role = [PFRole roleWithName:@"Administrator" acl:roleACL];
[role saveInBackground];

if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
    // Create the log in view controller
    CustomLoginViewController *logInViewController = [[CustomLoginViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate.

    // Create the sign up view controller
    CustomSignupViewController *signUpViewController = [[CustomSignupViewController alloc] init];
    [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
    [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

    // Present the log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
} else {
    PFQuery *queryRole = [PFRole query];
    [queryRole whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Administrator"];
    [queryRole getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFRole *role = (PFRole *)object;
        PFRelation *adminRelation = [role users];
        PFQuery *queryAdmins = [adminRelation query];
        [queryAdmins whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
        [queryAdmins getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && [object.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
                SelectUserViewController * GPVC = [[SelectUserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectUserViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self presentViewController:GPVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            }

        }];
    }];
}
```

}

I also have another query further down in the shouldBeginSignUp section. This is really bugging me and my mentors won't submit my app. with the query as it stands.

Comment: You should consult the UIViewController documentation to find a more appropriate method. This is viewDidAppear:'s expected behavior.

Comment: You _could_ put this code inside of the viewDidLoad method but a better place would be outside of this view controller entirely. The less code you put in your view controllers the better.

Comment: You just fixed it CrimsonChris, you just did it FINALLY! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just thanking CrimsonChris, putting the following code above in the viewDidLoad means the query will only be action the first time the user goes to the main menu and not every time. Solution solved. Thanks Chris,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about putting this code into a separate model object that handles your webservices, especially if other view controllers will be making web calls... It's much cleaner (and in the spirit of MVC) to have those related pieces of non-UI functionality grouped together in a proper model!